# Promote artifact version to single environment using VS Team Services Release Management

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

In VS Team Services > Releases, I want to 'promote' a specific build/artifact version to a single environment.  For example:

```
Dev     QA     Prod
v223       
v123   v123
```

I want to promote #123 to Prod, but it looks like the only way to do that is to Create a release to all 3 environments, which will overwrite #223.

[image]

Comment: Why are you not able to promote your first release (the one in Alfa) to Prod?

Comment: I can - but I can only release to a 'final destination', and it also releases to all environments in the pipeline.  So if I have a newer build in Dev (but still testing) it will get overwritten. @MrHinsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this for now. You can submit a feature request on VSTS User Voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/

Comment: Thanks! This seems pretty common in DevOps, and tools like Octopus Deploy do this.

Comment: You can clone the release pipeline and delete the first two stages to create a single stage release.

Comment: Octopus is deployment with release bolted on. Traceability was not the original purpose.

Comment: @MrHinsh yes that is a workaround - I shouldn't have to create a single stage release for every component & every environment.

Comment: You should not be bypassing your release process! Why can't you push your v123 that is currently in Alfa to production?

Comment: Say #123 had some bugs, and #223 fixed them.  I wouldn't push #123 to production, I would promote #223 through the pipeline

Comment: fyi - this has been ad added feature in their Release Management pipeline.  I got an email about it around the middle of February 2015!

Answer (score 1):

You have a release pipeline that goes Dev -> QA -> Prod. You create a release for version #123 and promote it progressively through the stages in your pipeline. Version #223 can be in Dev, and you can still promote the release for build #123 from QA->Production.

Skipping stages and not testing software in lower environments is a huge problem that results in pain and suffering. One of the cornerstones of a stable release process is **consistency**. There are tons of ways to make your release process both flexible enough to handle the scenario you're describing while still being consistent. Skipping stages isn't it.

If you need to re-release an older build of your software, **it should still go through the same pipeline**. Just because it's an old build doesn't mean that you don't need to at least do a cursory investigation to make sure it's being deployed correctly.

Will that overwrite the version currently on the lower environments? Depends on how you structure things! For web applications, maybe you make it multi-tenant, so you can have multiple versions running side-by-side on the same machine. Or deploy to IaaS VMs, so you can just provision a new one and leave the currently-running VM alone. Or deploy to Azure PaaS and use different staging slots for different versions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I agree with you completely.  My question is how to do your first paragraph in VSO.  I cannot find a 'promote' button.  So when I do want to promote #123 to Prod, it looks like I can only 'release' to all environments. So it wipes away my dev and puts #123 in all environments.  Its weird....

Comment: You have a release of v123 currently in Alfa. Open that release and promote it to production.